# How to apply gradient effect based on image background color in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Hey guys How can I achieve this effect, apply a gradient in the background based on the image color.? can anyone recommend any packages or links to any snippets?

[image: Gradient Image Flutter]

Thank you

Comment: can you provide some details on what you alreday tried?

Comment: I couldn't get a start with it, I was checking out this package 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blurhash, but it does the hash as placeholder

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/palette_generator - the docs say: *"A Flutter package to extract prominent colors from an Image, typically used to find colors for a user interface."*

Comment: Hey @pskink, Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for.